# Reding a file and storing the string as well as numeric value in array in specific format

Tags: java

I have a input file named file.txt with the contents

```
Zone
Diameter    5
-321    -560    5811
-209    -580    2935
-27     -409    3580
-1075   -220    2847
-1045   206     2827
-19     410     3570
-205    570     2929
-310    565     5768
2.0     3.0     2.0
Zone
Diameter    50
4379    461     23390
484     -264    13447
1259    -516    11969
182     -669    9530
1366    -931    12720
1553    2350    -18702
-3458    6112   -24596
-3606   -6347   -24995
1491    -2267   -18694
1315    835     12740
193     631     9525
12      1252    490     11942
13      520     211     13311
14      4308    -174    23624
```

I am looking for an output like:

```
    zone=1
    x=[1.0 2.0 1.0 2.0 1.0.......2.0 1.0]
    similarly y=[]
    z=[]
    then
    zone=2
    x=[5.0 25.0 15 25 41 25 16 25]
    similarly y=[]
    z=[]
```

However, I am getting the values of x=[] for zone=2 from the starting of zone=1, as I am using x.add(scanner.nextDouble()).

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package boltcal1103;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author Neha
 */
public class NewMain {
private static ArrayList<Double> x;
private static ArrayList<Double> y;
private static ArrayList<Double> z;
private static String next1;

/**
* @param args the command line arguments
*/
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    // TODO code application logic here
    //File file1 = new File("file.txt");

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader("file1.txt"));
    String line=null,word="Zone",next = null, next1=null;
    int count=1;
    while(scanner.hasNext()) {
        line = scanner.nextLine();
        if (line.equals(word)) {
            if (count > 1) {
                System.out.println(x);
                System.out.println(y);
                System.out.println(z);
            }
            //    int b;
            //  String next1;
            if(scanner.hasNextLine()){
                String nextLine1 = scanner.next();
                System.out.println("name :"+nextLine1);
                //   scanner.useDelimiter("\t");
                if(scanner.hasNext())
                {

                    //   scanner.useDelimiter(" ");
                    next1 = scanner.next();
                    System.out.println("value of diameter:"+next1);
                    //b = Integer.parseInt(scanner.next());
                    //System.out.println("value of diameter:"+b);
                    //      scanner.useDelimiter("\n");
                    scanner.nextLine();
            }}




            System.out.println("zone=:"+count);
            count++;
            x = new ArrayList<Double>();
            y = new ArrayList<Double>();
            z = new ArrayList<Double>();
        }


        else {
            // String delims="";
            String[] d = line.split("\t");
            //         System.out.println("zone=:"+d);

            x.add(Double.parseDouble(d[0]));
            y.add(Double.parseDouble(d[1]));
            z.add(Double.parseDouble(d[2]));
            //      System.out.println("zone=:"+count);
            //  System.out.println(d[0]);
            //  System.out.println(d[1]);
            //  System.out.println(d[2]);
            int i;
            for(i=0;i<x.size();i++)
            {
                Double get1 = x.get(i);
                // System.out.println("value of x:"+get1);
                Double get2 = y.get(i);

                Double get3 = z.get(i);
                double x1 = get1*get1;
                double y1 = get2*get2;
                double z1 = get3*get3;
                System.out.println("x1:"+x1+"\ty1:"+y1+"\tz1:"+z1);


        } }

    }

    if (count > 1) {
        System.out.println(x);
        System.out.println(y);
        System.out.println(z);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you state clearly what you get now and what you would expect? I still fail to understand...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could move

```
List<Double> x = new ArrayList<Double>();   //Defining double arraylist for Fx
List<Double> y = new ArrayList<Double>();   //Defining double arraylist for Fy
List<Double> z = new ArrayList<Double>();   //Defining double arraylist for Fz
```

inside your while loop, so the lists would be reset after each zone.

**EDIT** Since you want to support zones of arbitrary size, make your while loop like:

```
while(scanner.hasNext()) {
    line = scanner.next();
    if (next.equals(word)) {
        if (count > 1) {
            System.out.println(x);
            System.out.println(y);
            System.out.println(z);
        }

        System.out.println("zone=:"+count);
        count++;
        x = new ArrayList<Double>();
        y = new ArrayList<Double>();
        z = new ArrayList<Double>();
    } else {
        String[] d = line.split(' ');
        x.add(Double.parseDouble(d[0]);
        y.add(Double.parseDouble(d[1]);
        z.add(Double.parseDouble(d[2]);
    }
}

if (count > 1) {
    System.out.println(x);
    System.out.println(y);
    System.out.println(z);
}
```

Comment: for(int i = 0; i<8 ; i++)
     {

     x.add(scanner.nextDouble());
     y.add(scanner.nextDouble());
     z.add(scanner.nextDouble());

     }

Comment: how to get a variable instead of 8 in the for loop, which is basically the number of lines between the zone.

Comment: for(int i = 0; i<8 ; i++) { x.add(scanner.nextDouble()); y.add(scanner.nextDouble()); z.add(scanner.nextDouble()); }

Comment: how to get a variable instead of 8 in the for loop, which is basically the number of lines between the zone.

Comment: Is this number fixed? That is, do all zones have the same number of lines? Or do you want to detect the number of lines?

Comment: this is my input file "file.txt" with the contents

Comment: Zone
Diameter 5mm
-321 -560 5811
-209 -580 2935
-27 -409 3580
-1075 -220 2847
-1045 206 2827
-19 410 3570
-205 570 2929
-310 565 5768
Zone
Diameter 7mm
4379 461 23390
484 -264 13447
1259 -516 11969
182 -669 9530
1366 -931 12720
Zone
Diameter 4mm
4379 461 23390
484 -264 13447
1259 -516 11969
182 -669 9530
1366 -931 12720
1553 2350 -18702
-3458 6112 -24596
-3606 -6347 -24995
1259 -516 11969
182 -669 9530
1366 -931 12720

Comment: Since you don't know beforehand whether you'll get a string (zone) or three doubles, you should read every line as a string, test if it equals `zone`, and if not, parse the doubles.

Comment: Dear Heuster, I did that... I have another problem in the continuation of the above file. After reading the many zones and corresponding x, y, and z values. I am performing addition of x and y; y and z and so on. but I am only getting the values of last zone for the calculation. If I put for loop inside the while(), the code gives the values of x+y etc for each x.size().        Thanks in advance for your views.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you try to add. Do you mean all x-values per zone, or each x+y per row, or something completely different?

Comment: I WANT TO add another column (column 4) with some new calculations (for example x+y), where x is in first column and y is in second column. But I have "zone" in between of them.          I'll put the code if you would like to see ...

Comment: Do you want to write that back into the same file?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you can write those in the else-block of the while loop, since you are handling the data there. If that doesn't answer your question, I would need to see the code ;-)

Comment: added the original java file. however I was doing in the same manner as you told above but it is writing multiple time dont know where exactly I should print the values,,, thanks again